# command to find the number of entries in a temp table

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

What is the command to find the number of entries/rows in a temp table? version 10.2b

Comment: Ok thanks. Why does this deserve a down vote?!?! I looked everywhere and couldn't find one so I though I would ask here in case i was missing something.

Comment: @Bill There's nothing wrong with your question. People are probably just mad that you're highlighting a major deficiency in OpenEdge's most core data structure

Comment: Some people just view everything through a "Progress sucks" lens.  When you take the blinders off things usually go better.

Comment: @TomBascom Couldn't agree with you more

Comment: Don't be fooled, people, Progress does suck. It even gets worse with the blinders off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/* create a temp-table so that we can test this technique
 */

define temp-table ttTest
  field id as int
.

create ttTest.
id = 1.
create ttTest.
id = 2.

/* how many records?
 */

define query q for ttTest cache 0.
open query q preselect each ttTest.
display num-results( "q" ).
```

Comment: It's too bad there isn't a `NUM-RECORDS` attribute for temp-table objects. Surely a temp-table knows exactly how many rows it contains, and being single-threaded, Progress doesn't have any type of concurrency complications to worry about. Weird that they thought to add a `HAS-RECORDS` attribute to check for emptiness but not one with the actual number.

Comment: I had the same thought.  I'll try to remember to suggest it the net time I'm providing helpful input to development ;)

Answer (score 1):

or you can use clasic FOR EACH:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE iCount AS INT NO-UNDO.

FOR EACH ttTest:
  iCount = iCount + 1.
END.

DISPLAY iCount.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's mine, that works for any temp-table :

```
FUNCTION TT_NBREC RETURNS INTEGER ( INPUT pr_hd_temptable AS HANDLE ) :

    DEFINE VARIABLE in_nbrec  AS INTEGER   NO-UNDO INITIAL 0.
    DEFINE VARIABLE hd_buffer AS HANDLE    NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE VARIABLE hd_query  AS HANDLE    NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE VARIABLE ch_query  AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE VARIABLE ch_table  AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE VARIABLE lg_error  AS LOGICAL   NO-UNDO.

    ASSIGN
        ch_table = pr_hd_temptable:NAME
        ch_query = "FOR EACH " + ch_table + " NO-LOCK".
    CREATE BUFFER hd_buffer FOR TABLE ch_table.
    CREATE QUERY  hd_query.
    hd_query:ADD-BUFFER( hd_buffer ).
    lg_error = hd_query:QUERY-PREPARE( ch_query ) NO-ERROR.
    hd_query:QUERY-OPEN().
    hd_query:GET-FIRST().
    DO WHILE NOT hd_query:QUERY-OFF-END :
        ASSIGN in_nbrec = in_nbrec + 1.
        hd_query:GET-NEXT().
    END.
    hd_query:QUERY-CLOSE().
    DELETE OBJECT hd_query.
    DELETE OBJECT hd_buffer.
    ASSIGN
        hd_query  = ?
        hd_buffer = ?.

    RETURN in_nbrec.
END FUNCTION.
```

Just pass it the handle of your temp-table and you get the number of records.
It can certainly be improved, but it works fast enough for me.